# No puedo enviar mensaje a gmail usando PHP en Windows

Tags: php

tengo este error que puedo hacer no puedo enviar un mensaje a gmail por php windows

> Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail

```
-language: php
php:
  - 7.0
  - 5.6
  - 5.5
  - 5.4
  - 5.3
  - hhvm

matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - php: hhvm

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -y -qq postfix
before_script:
  - sudo service postfix stop
  - smtp-sink -d "%d.%H.%M.%S" localhost:2500 1000 &
  - mkdir -p build/logs
  - cd test
  - cp testbootstrap-dist.php testbootstrap.php
  - chmod +x fakesendmail.sh
  - sudo mkdir -p /var/qmail/bin
  - sudo cp fakesendmail.sh /var/qmail/bin/sendmail
  - sudo cp fakesendmail.sh /usr/sbin/sendmail
  - echo 'sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i "' > $(php --ini|grep -m 1 "ini files in:"|cut -d ":" -f 2)/sendmail.ini
script:
  - phpunit --configuration ../travis.phpunit.xml.dist
after_script:
  - wget https://scrutinizer-ci.com/ocular.phar
  - php ocular.phar code-coverage:upload --format=php-clover ../build/logs/clover.xml
```

estas son las paginas donde esta el error

```
 public $Sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';






public function isSendmail()
    {
        $ini_sendmail_path = ini_get('sendmail_path');

        if (!stristr($ini_sendmail_path, 'sendmail')) {
            $this->Sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
        } else {
            $this->Sendmail = $ini_sendmail_path;
        }
        $this->Mailer = 'sendmail';
    }






public function testMailSend()
    {
        $sendmail = ini_get('sendmail_path');
        //No path in sendmail_path
        if (strpos($sendmail, '/') === false) {
            ini_set('sendmail_path', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i ');
        }
        $this->Mail->Body = 'Sending via mail()';
        $this->buildBody();

        $this->Mail->Subject = $this->Mail->Subject . ': mail()';
        $this->Mail->isMail();
        $this->assertTrue($this->Mail->send(), $this->Mail->ErrorInfo);
        $msg = $this->Mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
        $this->assertNotContains("\r\n\r\nMIME-Version:", $msg, 'Incorrect MIME headers');
    }
```

Comment: Necesitas tener activado un "servidor de email", configura sendemail en xampp
[configurar xampp y mercury para enviar emails desde localhost](https://www.jsolucioncreativa.com/wordpress/enviar-emails-de-wordpress-con-xampp/)

Comment: de hecho la linea `/usr/sbin/sendmai` es una ruta de sistemas operativo opensource

Answer (score 0):

Ojalá te ayude en algo, si tienes **XAMPP** instalado en tu PC y quieres enviar desde tu localhost emails, quizas no configuraste el archivo `xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`
Ahi te pide los datos de tu **SMTP** del servidor de salida (importante para poder enviar correos)

Archivo sendmail.ini
EJ.

```
[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=TU.SMTP <---aqui tu SMTP (PUEDE SER mail.tudominio.com)

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25   <---aqui tu puerto (por defecto es 25)

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=TUDOMINIO.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=TU@EMAIL.COM   <---aqui tu email
auth_password=TUPASSWORD   <---aqui tu clave
```

////

También trata de ver que estén activadas las extensiones **SMTP**, **IMAP**, en tu `php.ini` y `httpd.conf`, colocándole las opciones de correo, (que debe ser un correo válido en un servidor tipo `hostgator, bluehost, godaddy, etc`)